R6 class function: Error in self$assert(xs) : Assertion on 'xs' failed
I modified a function in an R6 class defining a pipeline step for supervised learning, specifically using cross-validation (CV). This class encapsulates a learner and performs cross-validation on the training data (see also this link for more details).
When running this function, I get the following error message:
Error in self$assert(xs) : 
  Assertion on 'xs' failed: Parameter 'keep_response' not available. Did you mean 'resampling.method' / 'resampling.folds' / 'resampling.repeats'?.

The problem comes from this line of code:
super$initialize(id, alist(resampling = private$.crossval_param_set, private$.learner$param_set), param_vals = param_vals, can_subset_cols = TRUE, task_type = task_type, tags = c("learner", "ensemble"))

I have put print() statements everywhere, but every time the variable keep_response appears. I am completely new to object-oriented programming in R, so your help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a reproducible example to use the function:
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:1742, x = runif(1742, -130.88, -61.12), y = runif(1742, 12.12, 61.38), year = runif(1742, 2005, 2020), presence = rep(0:1, each=871), V1 = runif(1742, -3.66247, 2.95120), V2 = runif(1742, -1.6501, 7.5510))
data$presence <- as.factor(data$presence)
## summary(data)

task <- mlr3spatial::as_task_classif_st(x = data, target = "presence", positive = "1", coordinate_names = c("x", "y"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
task$set_col_roles("ID", roles = "space")
task$set_col_roles("year", roles = "time")

source("H:/PipeOpLearnerCV_mod.R")
learner_glmboost <- mlr3::lrn("classif.glmboost", predict_type = "prob", family = "Binomial")

po_learner_glmboost <- PipeOpLearnerCV_mod$new(learner = learner_glmboost, param_vals = list(resampling.method = "sptcv_cstf", resampling.folds = 2, keep_response = FALSE))

Here is the function with my edits and print():
PipeOpLearnerCV_mod = R6Class("PipeOpLearnerCV_mod",
                          inherit = PipeOpTaskPreproc,
                          public = list(
                            initialize = function(learner, id = NULL, param_vals = list()){
                              private$.learner = as_learner(learner, clone = TRUE)
                              if(mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old){
                                private$.learner$param_set$set_id = ""
                              }
                              ########################################################################
                              ## My edits
                              id = ifelse(is.null(id), private$.learner$id, id)
                              print(id)
                              ## id = id %??% private$.learner$id
                              # FIXME: can be changed when mlr-org/mlr3#470 has an answer
                              ########################################
                              type = private$.learner$task_type
                              task_type = mlr_reflections$task_types[type, mult = "first"]$task
                              
                              ########################################################################
                              ## My edits
                              private$.crossval_param_set = ps(
                                method = p_fct(levels = c("cv", "insample", "sptcv_cstf", "repeated_sptcv_cstf"), tags = c("train", "required")),
                                folds = p_int(lower = 2L, upper = Inf, tags = c("train", "required")), 
                                repeats = p_int(lower = 1L, upper = Inf),
                                stratify = p_lgl(default = FALSE),
                                keep_response = p_lgl(tags = c("train", "required"))
                              )

                              ## My edits
                              if(param_vals$resampling.method == "sptcv_cstf"){private$.crossval_param_set$values = list(method = param_vals$resampling.method, 
                                                                                                                         folds = param_vals$resampling.folds, 
                                                                                                                         keep_response = param_vals$keep_response)
                              print(private$.crossval_param_set$values)}
                              
                              if(param_vals$resampling.method == "repeated_sptcv_cstf"){private$.crossval_param_set$values = list(method = param_vals$resampling.method, 
                                                                                                                         folds = param_vals$resampling.folds,
                                                                                                                         repeats = param_vals$resampling.repeats,
                                                                                                                         keep_response = param_vals$keep_response)
                              print(private$.crossval_param_set$values)}
                              
                              if(param_vals$resampling.method == "cv" || param_vals$resampling.method == "insample"){private$.crossval_param_set$values = list(method = "cv", folds = 3, keep_response = FALSE)
                              print(private$.crossval_param_set$values)}
                              
                              if(mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old){
                                private$.crossval_param_set$set_id = "resampling"
                              }
                              # Dependencies in paradox have been broken from the start and this is known since at least a year:
                              # https://github.com/mlr-org/paradox/issues/216
                              # The following would make it _impossible_ to set "method" to "insample", because then "folds"
                              # is both _required_ (required tag above) and at the same time must be unset (because of this
                              # dependency). We will opt for the least annoying behaviour here and just not use dependencies
                              # in PipeOp ParamSets.
                              # private$.crossval_param_set$add_dep("folds", "method", CondEqual$new("cv"))  # don't do this.
                              ########################################################################
                              
                              print("A")
                              a <- private$.crossval_param_set
                              print(a)
                              print("B")
                              b <- private$.learner$param_set
                              print(b)
                              print("C")
                              c <- param_vals
                              print(c)
                              print("D")
                              print(id)
                              print("E")
                              print(task_type)
                              
                              super$initialize(id, alist(resampling = private$.crossval_param_set, private$.learner$param_set), param_vals = param_vals, can_subset_cols = TRUE, task_type = task_type, tags = c("learner", "ensemble"))
                              print("F")
                            }
                            
                          ),
                          active = list(
                            learner = function(val){
                              if(!missing(val)){
                                if(!identical(val, private$.learner)){
                                  stop("$learner is read-only.")
                                }
                              }
                              private$.learner
                            },
                            learner_model = function(val){
                              if(!missing(val)){
                                if(!identical(val, private$.learner)){
                                  stop("$learner_model is read-only.")
                                }
                              }
                              if(is.null(self$state) || is_noop(self$state)){
                                private$.learner
                              } else {
                                multiplicity_recurse(self$state, clone_with_state, learner = private$.learner)
                              }
                            },
                            predict_type = function(val){
                              if(!missing(val)){
                                assert_subset(val, names(mlr_reflections$learner_predict_types[[private$.learner$task_type]]))
                                private$.learner$predict_type = val
                              }
                              private$.learner$predict_type
                            }
                          ),
                          private = list(
                            .train_task = function(task){
                              on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                              
                              # Train a learner for predicting
                              self$state = private$.learner$train(task)$state
                              pv = private$.crossval_param_set$values
                              print(pv)
                              

                              # Compute CV Predictions
                              if(pv$method != "insample"){
                                rdesc = mlr_resamplings$get(pv$method)
                                if(pv$method == "cv"){rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds)}
                                ########################################################################
                                ## My edits
                                if(pv$method == "sptcv_cstf"){rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, stratify = pv$stratify)}
                                if(pv$method == "repeated_sptcv_cstf"){rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, repeats = pv$repeats, stratify = pv$stratify)}
                                ########################################################################
                                rr = resample(task, private$.learner, rdesc)
                                prds = as.data.table(rr$prediction(predict_sets = "test"))
                              } else {
                                prds = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                              }
                              
                              private$pred_to_task(prds, task)
                            },
                            
                            .predict_task = function(task){
                              on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                              private$.learner$state = self$state
                              prediction = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                              private$pred_to_task(prediction, task)
                            },
                            
                            pred_to_task = function(prds, task){
                              if(!is.null(prds$truth)) prds[, truth := NULL]
                              if(!self$param_set$values$resampling.keep_response && self$learner$predict_type == "prob"){
                                prds[, response := NULL]
                              }
                              renaming = setdiff(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                              data.table::setnames(prds, renaming, sprintf("%s.%s", self$id, renaming))
                              
                              # This can be simplified for mlr3 >= 0.11.0;
                              # will be always "row_ids"
                              row_id_col = intersect(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                              data.table::setnames(prds, old = row_id_col, new = task$backend$primary_key)
                              task$select(character(0))$cbind(prds)
                            },
                            .crossval_param_set = NULL,
                            .learner = NULL,
                            .additional_phash_input = function() private$.learner$phash
                          )
)

mlr_pipeops$add("learner_cv", PipeOpLearnerCV_mod, list(R6Class("Learner", public = list(id = "learner_cv", task_type = "classif", param_set = ps()))$new()))

